# Typed wrapper for retrieving attributes in C#

Tags: c#, attributes, extension-methods

There is custom attribute that allows to declare extension of a file used for serialize some class:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = false)]
public sealed class FileExtensionAttribute : Attribute {  
  readonly string extension;
  readonly string description;
  public FileExtensionAttribute(string extension, string description) {
    this.extension = extension;
    this.description = description;
  }
  public string Extension { get { return extension; } }
  public string Description { get { return description; } }
  public string GetFilterString() { return string.Format("{0}|*.{1}", description, extension); }
}
```

I marked some class with it:

```
[FileExtension("users", "Contestants DB")]
public class UsersDB {
  //...
}
```

So now I use reflection to retrieve `GetFilterString()` result:

```
string filter = (Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(UsersDB), typeof(FileExtensionAttribute)) as FileExtensionAttribute).GetFilterString();
saveFileDialog.Filter = filter;
openFileDialog.Filter = filter;
```

I want to write more expressive and less long-winded, something like this:

```
UsersDB.Attributes.FileExtension.GetFilterString();
```

or at least

```
AttributesOf(UsersDB).FileExtension.GetFilterString();
```

And I wish this syntax for any attributes and classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could extend the object like this

```
static class ObjectExtends
{

    public static T GetAttribute<T>(this object obj) where T : Attribute
    {
        return (T)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(obj.GetType(), typeof(T));
    }
    public static T GetAttribute<T>(Type t) where T : Attribute
    {
        return (T)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(t, typeof(T));
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
string s = "Hello World";
s.GetAttribute<SomeAttribute>();
```

or

```
ObjectExtends.GetAttribute<SomeAttribute>(typeof(SomeClass));
```